# Происхождение слова "забубенный"

Tags: этимология

"Забубенным" называют бесшабашного, лихого (в хорошем смысле этого слова) человека. А откуда это слово взялось? При чем тут бубен или бубны (карточная масть)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//=======
 Интересное это слово – забубённый. Интересно оно тем, что у него сразу несколько несовпадающих значений.

Одно значение слова забубённый связано с бубенчиками, бубенцами, простейшими музыкальными инструментами, которые использовали скоморохи. Скоморохи в своих выступлениях могли позволить себе высмеивать власть имущих, что привлекало на их головы гнев последних, одновременно  повышало интерес простой публики. За такую крамолу можно было и головы не сносить, за что скоморохов называли забубённые головы или забубённые головушки.

Этим выражение называли также и картежников, потому, что на старинных игральных картах бубновую масть обозначали не ромбом, как теперь, а бубенцами.

Ну, и, наконец, во второй половине девятнадцатого столетия забубёнными головушками стали называть каторжников, которым на арестантскую робу нашивали красные ромбы, (что соответствует общепринятому обозначению бубновой масти в картах),  чтобы в случае попытки к бегству конвоирам было легче целится в бегуна.

Забубённый, или забубённая головушка является характеристикой людей отчаянных, пропащих, способных на все.
//=======

http://esperanto-plus.ru/fraz/z/zabubennij.htm

Даже добавить нечего, основное значение забубенный (лихой, бесшабашный) - от самого древнего, "скоморошьего", знначения.

Впрочем, стоит упомянуть о версии Даля (хотя он никогда не был авторитетом в таких вопросах):
 ЗАБУБЁННЫЙ
Образовано от бубен; так называли и до сих пор называют разновидность барабана. У барабана (бубна) есть одно не очень очевидное свойство, которое не осталось незамеченным народной мудростью: он - голый. А от голого до бедного один шаг, и вскоре слово бубен стало значить "бедняк". Ну а впоследствии от него было образовано причастие забубённый, имеющее значение "бесшабашный", "гуляка".

Answer (score 2):

Заключенным на каторге на спину нашивали ромбик - "бубну". Поэтому забубённый - арестант, преступник, лихой человек.

Comment: Увы, это всего лишь одно из поздних значений, сам слово гораздо древнее.
см. - мой ответ

Answer (score 1):

Этимологию слова "забубённый" вряд ли возможно определить точно, и версий очень много. Из не высказанных предыдущими, отвечающими можно назвать Фасмера.

> забубенный "нелепый; распущенный, буйный". Желтов (ФЗ, 1876, вып. I, стр. 9 и сл.) пытается объяснить из *забобо́нный – то же, забобо́ны "суеверие". Налицо по крайней мере влияние слова бу́бны мн.: забубённое пьянство, первонач. "пирушка с музыкой", затем – "буйное пьянство

и версию  из Большого толково-фразеологического словаря Михельсона, предлагающего сравнить выражение забубенная головушка со словом "бубень" — лентяй.
Версий ещё много, но остальные уже совсем маловероятные (от диалектного "забубны" (вздор), проигравшийся в карты, впавший в транс от бубна шамана, буби как символ жизни в гаданиях и пр.).

По мне так, самая логичная версия как раз у Фасмера. Каторжникам уже не порезвится, в картах  бубны масть не самая примечательная, а скоморохи вроде и подходят (Скоморох голос на гудки настроит, а житья своего не устроит), но непонятно почему из семантики слова исчезло основное качество скомороха - шутовство, веселить других, а не только себя.